# HMVC - Adding multiple models

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

```
modules
--customers
----controllers
-------customers.php
----models
-------customers_model.php
-------handler_model.php
```

Hi im trying to load two models in my controllers by using this:

```
class Customers extends CoreAPI
   {

public function __construct()
{
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model('Customers_model', 'Customers');
    $this->load->model('Customers/Handler_model');
}

 public function test_get()
 {
    $this->Handler_model->test; 

    exit;
 }
```

However, I always get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI::$test

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 73
```

I tried the two different ways of loading a model as stated.

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wewog.png)

Please help. Thank you.

```
class Handler_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent :: __construct();
    }


    public function test()
    {
        echo 'TEST'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: the message `Message: Undefined property: CI::$test` means the class `Cl` is not being call in current folder. Where is `Cl` come from?

Comment: i used the HMVC so it's located under \application\third_party\MX\Ci.php

Comment: has it being call in the current page?

Comment: my Handler _model extends to CI_Model class Handler_model extends CI_Model

Comment: Make sure in the `$test` has been declare in `Cl_Model` and accessible to public.

Comment: im accessing the test_get in my controller by loading the model. please see edit